# Logging suddenly stopped working in iOS app with xCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, nslog, xcode4.6

I am using xCode 4.6. I upgraded when it first came out, with no problem.

Today, logging suddenly stopped working in my app. It has been logging no problem since I first created the app (years ago), then today it just stopped.

I have tried:

*Cleaning the project

*Deleting the derived data

*Closing and restarting xcode

*Deleting the app from the simulator

*Resetting the simulator

*Searching to see if NSLog (or DLog, as I am mostly using, though I do use some NSLog as well) was redefined somewhere (they weren't)

I have looked at other posts on this site, and they have not helped the solve the problem. I really do not know what to do from here.

Comment: Can you use Breakpoints in Xcode?

Comment: But does it work in a completely new clean project? In other words, what's broken, Xcode or this one app?

Comment: Yes, I can use breakpoints. I have another project that works. Something must be broken in this app. But I did not, to the best of my knowledge, change anything that would have done this. This is a HUGE project, to move it to a new project will be murder.

Comment: Update: NSLog DOES work; but DLog does not. It is defined where it has always been defined, and that file is included in the prefix. I wonder if there is a problem with #ifdef DEBUG in the Run configuration..

Comment: That is it. Somehow the app does not recognize the DEBUG flag when it is Running.

Comment: Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Is '-DDEBUG' defined under 'Other C Flags'?

Comment: No it wasn't. But the app had been working successfully without it.. Right before I saw your comment I noticed that under Preprocessor Macros, the DEBUG flag was on the 'Any Architecture/Any SDK' line under 'Debug', but it was not on the 'Debug' line itself. Also, it said DEBUG and not DEBUG=1; I added DEBUG=1 directly to the 'Debug' line under Preprocessor Macros, and it worked. Do you think I also need to add -DDEBUG to Other C Flags? Would that take into account when I am not in Debug configuration? Thanks.

Comment: I will just add it under the Debug config. Sorry, rough day. If you want to add your comment as an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to choose Debug Configuration in Schema Info.

[image]